# Accessing struct data through a pointer in a Python C extension

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

So I'm trying to create a C extension and am having a bit of trouble accessing the struct data for one of my arguments. Here's my current code:

```c
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
} Point;


static PyObject *test(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    Point *start, *end = NULL;
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "OO", &start, &end)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    printf("%d %d\n", (int)start->x, (int)start->y);
    printf("%d %d\n", (int)end->x, (int)end->y);

    return PyLong_FromLong(0);
}
```

Python code which calls it:

```py
import testmodule

testmodule.test((5, 4), (7, 1))
```

I'm trying to get these inputs tuples to be converted into `Point` structs so they can be used further on in the program. Any idea how I can fix this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `"ii"` instead of `"OO"` to get integers.

Comment: How would I have the `(5, 4)` and `(7, 1)` be created as structs though?

Comment: I was confused, I was thinking you were parsing each element of the tuple.

Comment: I probably didn't make it clear enough, I wanted the input tuples to be converted into the `Point` structs.

Comment: You're clear, it was my own mistake.

Comment: I just made it clearer.

Comment: I think the pointers you pass to `PyArg_ParseTuple` should have a type of `PyObject *`, not `Point *`. Then you can cast it to `PyTupleObject *` and get the values using `PyTuple_GetItem`. I might be missing something though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect too much from `PyArg_ParseTuple`: its implementation knows nothing about the `Point`-struct which is defined by you - it has no idea how a tuple can be converted to a `Point` struct.

You have to provide the following information to `PyArg_ParseTuple`:

- arguments consist of two tuples
- each tuple has two integers inside
- first integer in the first tuple maps to `start.x`, second - to `start.y`
- first integer in the first tuple maps to `end.x`, second - to `end.y`

This all can be achieved with the following code:

```
    static PyObject *test(PyObject *args) {
        Point start, end;
        if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "(ii)(ii)", &start.x, &start.y, 
                                               &end.x, &end.y)) {
            return NULL;
        }

        printf("%d %d\n", start.x, start.y);
        printf("%d %d\n", end.x, end.y);

        return PyLong_FromLong(0);
    }
    """
```

As you can see:

- `PyArg_ParseTuple` will not allocate memory it writes values to existing memory, thus `start` and `end` are allocated on stack and aren't pointers.
- `"(ii)(ii)" tells to look for two tuples (`(...)` means tuple), each consisting of two integers.
- we give the addresses where the converted integer values should be stored, e.g. `&start.x`.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed comment explaining why my code didn't work, how to solve it and how the correct solution works. Its really appreciated.